# Ckeditor not applying to textarea

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I have a **`textarea`** field in a custom module form , I guess there is ckeditor library by default in core in d8 . I tried the following :

```
$form['fieldset']['email_template'] = array(
  '#type' => 'text_format',
  '#format' => 'full_html',
  '#title' => t('E-mail template content'),
  '#default_value' => "<br><br><br>" . $dvalue,
  '#description' => t('A valid template for email trigger.<b> Please type ":" for variable suggestions</b>'),
  '#attributes' => array(
                ),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#cols' => 60,
  '#resizable' => TRUE,
  '#rows' => 13,
  //'#wysiwyg' => TRUE,
            );
```

[image]

I followed the link : https://www.drupal.org/node/1031160

But the ckeditor is not applying to the textarea as expected . Any idea ??

**UPDATE**

I was not given the text_format as `ckeditor` in https://base_url/admin/config/content/formats . 
[image]
I defined a new format which can apply to which all fields needed as ckeditor . cheers

Comment: Any js errors in the console?

Comment: while creating a field text area in any content type ck editor is enabled .?? I aint talking about custom field

Comment: @ShreyaShetty the field is on a custom module form , not of any content type .

Comment: No am asking you to do it . So that we can validate if its a problem with ckeditor or the custom module

Comment: because i tried same code that worked for me . I dunno why it isnt working at your end

Comment: In content type forms also ckeditor is not applied  .I guess there is some enabling the ckeditor issue , I didnt see any menu option for ckeditor in d8 .

Comment: Yes you need yo enable ck editor in filters or formats yo wish below are steps follow that . You will achieve what you asked for .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `/admin/config/content/formats` and check the CKeditor is enabled for FULL HTML. Also, could be a role issue, by default Full HTML is for admins only.

[image]

### Important:

For safety/security reasons FULL HTML should be used by admins only. You're better off using `basic_html` as your format if this form is for authenticated or anonymous users. You may need to adjust the roles so anonymous can use it.

Comment: this should work ;)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) .https://192.168.1.243/modules/my_module/ckeditor/plugins/image2/plugin.js?t=F7J9

Comment: I defined a new template as 'ckeditor' and it worked :)) , kudos

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to configuration > Click Text formats and editors
2. you will find Full HTML option click on configure
3. Select Text editor has Ck Editor and whatever options you want and click on save

Run your code . You will find ckeditor in textarea